# Converse of L'Hôpital's

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f, g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and differentiable. Let $g'(x) \neq 0, x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L$, for some $L \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that
>   $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L.$$
>   (The notes have this as show $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L$, but I believe this is a typo because there are trivial counterexamples.)

Well, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both $0$ or undefined , l'Hôpital's tells us that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L$, given that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L .$
So, the cases we have left are when the limits of $f$ and $g$ are both finite, or one is undefined.

However, consider $f(x) = \arctan(x)$ and $g(x) = \arctan(x) + 100$. It is well known that $f$ and $g$ are continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. 
Then, $f'(x) = g'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$, so $g'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

But we have $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\arctan(x)}{\arctan{x} + 100} = \frac{\pi}{200 + \pi} \neq 1 = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}{\frac{1}{1+x^2}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$

Does anyone know the correct statement of this problem, or whether the converse of l'Hôpital's is false in general?

Comment: You can apply L'Hospital's rule if $f(x),g(x)\to 0$ or $\infty$ simultaneously. But not in other cases as you have realized.

Answer (score 0):

Well ya see we can only apply L'Hopitals when we get $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and in this case we don't get that as you wrote you get $\frac{\pi}{\pi+200}$